# What is an algorithm to find simple cycles?

Tags: algorithms, graph

I have a graph with an [Eulerian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_cycle) and no [Hamiltonian cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_Cycle). I would like to divide this graph into simple cycles.
Edges may not be repeated in simple cycles.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you have more than one edge between two nodes in your graph?

Comment: Also, can the simple cycles share nodes?

Comment: What does 'divide' mean? I don't think the questioner intended to imply a 'partition'. I guess that it's OK for a node to be in two or more simple cycles.

Comment: Oh. And do you actually have the Eulerian Cycle? Or do you simply know that such a cycle exists?

Comment: `Can you have more than one edge between two nodes in your graph?` Yes `Can you have more than one edge between two nodes in your graph?` No `What does 'divide' mean? I don't think the questioner intended to imply a 'partition'. I guess that it's OK for a node to be in two or more simple cycles.` Yes, you guess correctly

Answer (score 1):

Follow your Eulerian cycle. Whenever you arrive at a vertex you've been at before, the part between the two visits is a simple cycle. Chop that off and store it in the list of simple cycles, mark all vertices used in that, except the one you are at now, as unvisited. Continue until all edges have been used.

To find a Eulerian cycle, [Hierholzer's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_cycle#Hierholzer.27s_algorithm) is efficient.

Comment: This won't work. Cutting of the first simple cycle might leave the graph in a state that is not partitionable.

Comment: How that? After chopping off the first simple cycle, what's left is an Eulerian cycle in the graph minus the edges used in the simple cycle, as far as I can see.

Comment: @ThomasAhle seeing your answer, maybe I understand. I assumed OP already has a Eulerian cycle.

Comment: Well it is not hard to find an Eulerian cycle iirc, but in your solution I presume you are cutting out the nodes as well? I could construct an example with 5 nodes and an Eulerian cycle, where the first simple cycle I would find takes up four nodes. Then there is just one node left.

Comment: Hm, actually your method probably works, if the cycles are allowed to share a vertex.

Comment: This problem, answers, whatever, doesn't really seem to be a *programming* question, does it? It seem to be more of a ... theory question. Can someone involved elaborate?

Comment: I would only remove the nodes all of whose adjacent edges have been used. If there are still adjacent edges, we of course need the nodes for those.

Comment: @Lasse it's an algorithm question. Admittedly no programming yet involved, but as far as I know, stackexchange has not yet a more appropriate site for this type of question.

Comment: I'm not going to do anything about this question (yet), but the fact that SE does not have a more appropriate site for the question does not mean it is a question for SO. If I were to do anything about the question, it would be to close it as off-topic.

Comment: We shouldn't be cutting out cycles, I think. Check my answer for an example of simple cycles that shared nodes and edges with each other.

Comment: @Aaron sure, simple cycles can share nodes and edges. But if you decompose the E.C. into simple cycles, each edge is part of exactly one of the simple cycles. The decomposition is in general not uniqe, of course.

Comment: Does the questioner wants all the simple cycles, or just those within one particular Eulerian cycle, or to partition the edges of the EC into simple cycles? (I'm going to rethink my answer in either case, I feel like I'm unsure now what the question is never mind the answer!)

Comment: @Aaron I understood it as "partition into simple cycles". But my mind-reading skills are not above average.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already know the Eulerian cycle, use [Hierholzer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_cycle#Hierholzer.27s_algorithm).

(Edited to show how to find *every* simple cycle in the network, not just those contained within the EC. Is this what the questioner wanted?)

Assuming that you actually already know a Eulerian cycle, then simply follow the Eulerian cycle. Every time you visit a node that you have already visited, then you have found a *cycle*. You should check that it is a *simple cycle* by making sure  that there are no other repeats within this cycle. For example

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> B -> E -> A
```

`A ... A` is a cycle, and `B -> B` is a cycle, but only the latter is a *simple cycle*

Also, two simple cycles could share many nodes and edges with each other. For example,

```
A -> X -> B -> Y -> A -> Z -> B
```

`A ... A` and `B ... B` are simple cycles which share nodes and edges with each other.

**= Finding *every* simple cycle in the graph =**

Every simple cycle will either be contained with the Eulerian Cycle (EC), or will be spread out throughout the EC. For example of what I mean by 'spread out', we can see the simple cycle `A -> B -> C -> A` within this EC:

```
D -> A ==> B -> E -> F -> B ==> C ==> A -> D
```

where I've highlighted some edges by making them longer. Those edges form part of the simple cycle. So, given and EC and the goal to find *every* simple cycle, it's a question of enumerating all subsets of the edges in the EC.

But you can speed things up considerably with a simple observation. If you decide to include `A->B` in your *candidate simple cycle*, then the next edge that you decide to include must begin at B and you can then skip over many of the following edges. This should make it easier to ignore many large parts of the search tree.

In fact, I think this algorithm is pretty much optimum efficiency for finding all simple cycles. Any thoughts?

Comment: In hindsight, I now think this wouldn't be a good algorithm for finding *all* simple cycles. (But I'm going to try to stop thinking about this as I think the original question is not very clear)

Answer (score -1):

This problem is just as hard as finding a Hamiltonian cycle. I don't think you can use the fact that the graph has an Eulerian Cycle.

You can use the obvious `O(n!)` algorithm: For each permutation of nodes, go through the list and see if the path you take is a partitioning in simple graphs.

But you can probably do better using dynamic programming.